# How to call a javascript function with protobuf data

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers

I am having the below protobuf data I will like to call the below javascript function. How can I achieve this.

**Javascript link**

https://jsfiddle.net/maxspan/xyrc0w4d/

```
00000000: 7e6d 7e37 357e 6d7e 0829 1247 0a0f 7173  ~m~75~m~.).G..qs
00000001: 5f67 554d 4463 7556 514e 6837 3912 0f42  _gUMDcuVQNh79..B
00000002: 494e 414e 4345 3a42 5443 5553 4454 1a02  INANCE:BTCUSDT..
00000003: 6f6b 293d 0ad7 a3b0 7cc6 4035 0ad7 73c3  ok)=....|.@5..s.
00000004: 3de1 7a04 c051 5c05 31d0 037d cc40 9a01  =.z..Q\.1..}.@..
00000005: 027b 7d7e 6d7e 3735 7e6d 7e08 2912 470a  .{}~m~75~m~.).G.
00000006: 0f71 735f 4e7a 784f 7a4a 4d79 4277 6b6b  .qs_NzxOzJMyBwkk
00000007: 120f 4249 4e41 4e43 453a 4254 4355 5344  ..BINANCE:BTCUSD
00000008: 541a 026f 6b29 3d0a d7a3 b07c c640 350a  T..ok)=....|.@5.
00000009: d773 c33d e17a 04c0 515c 0531 d003 7dcc  .s.=.z..Q\.1..}.
0000000a: 409a 0102 7b7d                           @...{}
```

Comment: Please don't post a link to your code, post the code itself instead.

Comment: I cannot as the code is too long.

Comment: If it's too long for us to read, then strip it down to the relevant parts only: make a [mcve].